# Clear intent action default

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

I am launching the camera app in normal or secure mode depending on what gesture is performed using my app but once the user selects the app and taps Always then there is no option to change the defaults, even from the settings menu in Android.

```
camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
secure_camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE);
camera_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
secure_camera_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

this.startActivity(camera_intent);
//this.startActivity(secure_camera_intent);
```

Is there a workaround? I want to show the camera selection dialog once again so that the user can change his choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present the app chooser even if the user has a default activity selected for the task, use [Intent.createChooser()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

From the [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html):

> If you call Intent.createChooser(), passing it your Intent object, it
>   returns a version of your intent that will always display the chooser.
>   This has some advantages:
>
> - Even if the user has previously selected a default action for this    intent, the chooser will still be displayed.
> - If no applications match, Android displays a system message.
> - You can specify a title for the chooser dialog.

You should also check the documentation for [ACTION_CHOOSER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER) for guidelines on where this is appropriate or not (Intent.createChooser() is just a convenience method for this).

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(senderIntent, "Title here"));
```

It will always display the chooser dialog.

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It will always display the chooser.